# How do I sum a column in a child table of a projected linq query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, projection

I'm still pretty green on linq when it comes to projection and grouping. How can I get the results of the following SQL query using linq? Or is there a better approach to retrieving this query besides linq? I'm using entity framework and I know I can just hard code the sql but would prefer not to do that if there is a better way.

```
SELECT j.JobId, j.Name, j.OrderId, j.ShipDate, 
  st.ShipTypeId, sum(p.DeliveryCnt * p.Quantity) AS 'DeliveryCnt'
FROM Jobs j
JOIN ShipTo st ON j.JobId = st.JobId
JOIN DesignSets ds ON j.JobId = ds.JobId
JOIN DesignSetAreas dsa ON ds.DesignSetId = dsa.DesignSetId
JOIN Products p ON dsa.DesignSetAreaId = p.DesignSetAreaId
WHERE j.ShipDate >= '11/13/2016' AND j.ShipDate <= '11/26/2016'
GROUP BY j.JobId, j.Name, j.OrderId, j.ShipDate, st.ShipTypeId
```

The below code is what I have so far, but I'm not sure where or how I would do the grouping, or if this is even possible.

```
    var shipList = from j in db.Jobs
                   join st in db.ShipTo on j.JobId equals st.JobId
                   join ds in db.DesignSets on j.JobId equals ds.JobId
                   join p in db.Products on ds.DesignSetId equals p.DesignSetId
                   where j.ShipDate >= startDate && j.ShipDate <= endDate
                   select new ShipScheduleViewModel
                   {
                       JobId = j.JobId,
                       Name = j.OrderId + " " + j.Name,
                       ShipDay = ((DateTime)j.ShipDate).Day,
                       ShipVia = st.ShipTypeId,
                       Count = p.DeliveryCnt * p.Quantity
                   };
```

Comment: First I recommend that you embrace the use of navigation properties over joins https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: You're right about navigation properties. They are a much cleaner way to code. Thank you for that link to remind me there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `group by` syntax requires you to say what you want in the grouping (in this case the `p` `Products` are what you are aggregating in the `select`) and the values you want to group by (in this case the `j` `Job` and `st.ShipTypeId`) and finally you assign the grouping into a variable you can use in your `select`.

```
var shipList = from j in db.Jobs
               join st in db.ShipTo on j.JobId equals st.JobId
               join ds in db.DesignSets on j.JobId equals ds.JobId
               join p in db.Products on ds.DesignSetId equals p.DesignSetId
               where j.ShipDate >= startDate && j.ShipDate <= endDate
               group p by new { j, st.ShipTypeId } into grp
               select new ShipScheduleViewModel
               {
                   JobId = grp.Key.j.JobId,
                   Name = grp.Key.j.OrderId + " " + grp.Key.j.Name,
                   ShipDay = ((DateTime)grp.Key.j.ShipDate).Day,
                   ShipVia = grp.Key.ShipTypeId,
                   Count = grp.Sum(p => p.DeliveryCnt * p.Quantity)
               };
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a very fast response. It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You mentioned using navigation properties in your comment to my question. How would I achieve the same results using navigation properties? Specifically, retrieving the 'Count' property. Would I still need to do a Group By? Can you show me an example?

Comment: The navigation properties would allow you to not have to specify how to join tables because EF already knows.  It wouldn't have any effect on `Count` as that is an aggregation function and not a navigation property.